# Phantomjs opening many pages

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have been having some issues with opening multiple webpages in phantomjs, I am first opening a website which contains a few links, which I want to open as well, and save a piece of text from each URL to my jobs_list which has many objects inside of it. And after all the URL's have been run, I want to exit phantomjs. But as it is right now it never exits, and I have trouble recieving data from second function.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var jobs_list = [];

page.open('url', function (status) {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        };
        var list = page.evaluate(function() {

            var jobs = [];
            var job;

            $('.test').each(function(){
                $(this).find('span').each(function(){
                    var job_link = $(this).find('a');
                    var url = job_link.attr("href");

                    job = {title : job_link.text(), url : url, location : ""};
                    jobs.push(job);
                })
            });
            return jobs;
        });
        var i = 0;
        jobs_list = list;
        next_page(i);
    });
});


function next_page(i){
    if (i <= (jobs_list.length-1)) {
        var current_job = jobs_list[i];
        var url = current_job.url;

        page.open(url, function (status) {
            page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {


                var location = page.evaluate(function() {
                    var job_location;
                    $('.job-location').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                            job_location = $(this).text();
                        })
                    })
                    console.log(job_location);
                    return job_location;
                });
                jobs_list[i].location = location;

                if(i == (jobs_list.length-1)) {
                    phantom.exit(0);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(i, current_job.title);

        next_page(++i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `page.open` call is asynchronous. If you look closely to your `next_page` function it can be shortened to this:

```
function next_page(i){
    if (i <= (jobs_list.length-1)) {
        var current_job = jobs_list[i];
        var url = current_job.url;

        page.open(url, function (status) {
            ...
        });
        console.log(i, current_job.title);

        next_page(++i);
    }
}
```

It means that `next_page(++i);` is executed before `page.open(url, ...)` even managed to load the first HTML content. This call leads to the next `page.open(url, ...)` being executed immediately, thus overwriting the previous request. And you're never going to get any data this way.

You have to do two things:

- move the `next_page(++i);` call where the execution of one page is finished
- reduce the number of condition checking

I propose:

```
function next_page(i){
    if (i <= (jobs_list.length-1)) {
        var current_job = jobs_list[i];
        var url = current_job.url;

        page.open(url, function (status) {
            page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function () {

                var location = page.evaluate(function() {
                    var job_location;
                    $('.job-location').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                            job_location = $(this).text();
                        })
                    })
                    console.log(job_location);
                    return job_location;
                });
                jobs_list[i].location = location;

                console.log(i, current_job.title);
                next_page(++i);
            });
        });
    } else {
        phantom.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

That's quite an old version of jQuery. Perhaps you want to load a newer version. If the page already has jQuery included, you will likely break the page by loading another jQuery into it. Don't load an additional jQuery version at all in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you made my day!

Comment: Would it make any difference to do `return next_page(++i)` and have a `return` in the `else` clause and have the `phantom.exit(0)` after the initial call? Would there be any kind of memory leak exiting like you do with a full stack?

Comment: @CoolBlue I'm not really sure what you mean. Both in my code and in OP's code, `next_page(++i)` is the last statement in the surrounding function. Whether you return it or not doesn't make a difference. Although, there are cases where this can be done.

Comment: Hi. No, I'm just curious about exiting phantomjs without unravelling the recursion of the `next_page` function.  When you exit, you have `jobs_list.length` stack frames and execution contexts because of the recursion.  In the mod I asked about, I'm just using `return next_page(++i)` as a compact way to drop back through the call stack on completion (after hitting a `return` that I suggested in the else clause), it's not about returning a value.  I'm just interested in your thoughts about unravelling (or not) the call stack before exiting phantomjs.

Comment: @CoolBlue I'm not sure how the call stack is exactly implemented in PhantomJS' `page.open`, but generally the callback function of an asynchronous function will get a new call stack, so you generally don't have to worry about that. I know that I've answered a question where I tried to find the maximum size of the call stack in PhantomJS for `setTimeout` and I've stopped after an [hour without success](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33025179/1816580).